# svelte with electron is not showing html or not rendering svelte code properly

Tags: javascript, electron, svelte, sveltekit, commonjs

I am creating svelte app with electron, did basic setup and tried to run app after some initial error solving, now I am able to generate window with electron but I am not getting HTML output from svelte app.html page.

its showing me `%sveltekit.head% %sveltekit.body%` as an output instead of `Welcome to SvelteKit` and paragraph `Visit kit.svelte.dev to read the documentation` which is default output anyone ill get if they start svelte project using `npm run dev`.

if you add `"type: "commonjs"` in package.json, it is not allowing me to use import statememt, if i changed it to commonjs, it working and creating window but then it's not rendering svelte code in html output.

here is Whole code, you can clone and `npm install && npm run start` :
[Download from GIT REPO](https://github.com/BlackBeardo/snooker-svelte) .

I am not sure but I think `"type":"commonjs"` is the problem, but if I change it to `"type":"module"`, then my electron/index.js is causing problem.

need your help guys.

Comment: Being as svelte is a compiler, you cannot just open a source file (root index.html) and expect it to work. You could build sveltekit as a static site or single page application, but as I am not very familiar with electron I am not sure what else you might need to set up for it to work and serve all the files. A quick search brought up at least a couple of electron-sveltekit integrations you can use as a reference.

Comment: I've used this (https://github.com/FractalHQ/sveltekit-electron) as a starter for SvelteKit and Electron. It works well and should give you an idea of how to set things up.